# Trying to Design an online Student Exercise Database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm pretty new at MySQL and database structure and I was wondering if anyone could help with the best way to design this database.  The application is essentially an online exercise book. It will have exercises for students to complete and have the results stored in the database.

A Parent will be able to view their child's answers, while the Teacher can view their entire class' results.

I have 3 different types of users, `Teachers`, `Parents` and `Students`. each student is linked to a Parent, and each student is linked to a class.  A Teacher is linked to multiple classes.

My current structure for users can be seen here;

[image]

Should I create a single Users table and have a `UserType` field? If so how do I go about linking the student to a class and parent?

Comment: Whilst this is an interesting question it is too subjective for SO. It is likely to solicit opinion rather than having a single clear answer. Please read the section of the FAQ which gives guidance on [what _not_ to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: In the above schema, a student can only take one class. It would be better to have a join table with two fields, class and student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a schema for this:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `class`;

CREATE TABLE `class` (
  `class_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`class_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `class` */

insert  into `class`(`class_id`,`class_name`) values (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C');

/*Table structure for table `info` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `info`;

CREATE TABLE `info` (
  `info_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`info_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `info` */

insert  into `info`(`info_id`,`user_id`,`parent_id`,`class_id`) values (1,3,2,1);

/*Table structure for table `user` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `users_types_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `user` */

insert  into `user`(`user_id`,`user_name`,`users_types_id`,`class_id`) values (1,'TeacherA',1,1),(2,'Parent',2,0),(3,'StudentA',3,1),(4,'TeacherB',1,2),(5,'TeacherC',1,3);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users_types`;

CREATE TABLE `users_types` (
  `users_types_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_types_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `users_types` */

insert  into `users_types`(`users_types_id`,`type`) values (1,'Teacher'),(2,'Parent'),(3,'Student');
```

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6e09/1)

Also before insertion check if the record exists for user and parent in info table.

Comment: Wow thanks for that, it really helped a lot, I'm just a little confused with the menu table, so you suggest that I store menu options as a database? what's the method column for?

Comment: sorry i was testing this code in my localhost test db which already contained a table menu. i use codeigniter so method is the controller method or function

Comment: kindly delete this menu table it does not belong to your problem

Comment: haha, I see, well then that makes more sense, I didn't see a use for that for my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Things are much easier, if you look at your application from another angle. 
First of all, there's user entity, which provides all that authorisation functions, if user must have different functions — you better make different type of users:

```
Users:
id (int)
user_type_id   int
username       varchar
password       varchar
email          varchar

User_types:
id             int
name           varchar
```

If you use InnoDB engine, you can make a foreign key Users-User_types for the referential integrity.